# How to forecast electricity consumption using MATLAB's command "forecast"?

Tags: matlab, prediction, forecasting, forecast

I have the data of electricity consumption of a region during the year of 2017. So I have to matrix 1x1, one with the month and other with the consumption. I want to use the command `forecast` to forecast the consumption of the first month of 2018, but I don't know how to do this even after reading the examples on MATLAB's help page.

**Example:**

```
data = {1166974.25000000, 1132479.36000000, 1137173.86000000, 1145853.58000000, 1118875.72000000, 1071456.85000000 ,1047171.87000000, 1071179.65000000 ,1077986.32000000 ,1112111.10000000, 1149668.47000000 ,1161649.19000000, 1175576.25000000 ,1126753.31000000 ,1204843.11000000 ,1183946.03000000, 1153080.36000000, 1120182.07000000, 1104726.03000000 ,1108110.02000000 ,1137729.28000000 ,1189699.45000000, 1252975.55000000, 1218118.20000000 ,1259580 ,1208193 ,1194430, 1244458, 1218867, 1205705 ,1177362, 1185584, 1164758, 1226991 ,1286044 ,1305312, 1360681.70000000 ,1332020 ,1306497.90000000 ,1299819.10000000 ,1316167.70000000 ,1246959.40000000 ,1256700.20000000 ,1266490.60000000, 1275642.90000000, 1358839.80000000, 1361440.10000000, 1398059.40000000};
data = [data{:}];
sys = ar(data,4)
K = 49;
p = forecast(sys,data,K);
plot(data,'b',p,'r'), legend('measured','forecasted')
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution to your problem. If you have not, maybe I can be of assistance.

MathWork's documentation of the function notes that the "PastData" entry (labeled "data" in your code) can either be an iddata object or an N x N_y matrix of doubles. Your implementation uses a matrix, so I decided to try out the code with an iddata object.

```
rawdat = [1166974.25000000, 1132479.36000000, 1137173.86000000, 1145853.58000000, 1118875.72000000, 1071456.85000000 ,1047171.87000000, 1071179.65000000 ,1077986.32000000 ,1112111.10000000, 1149668.47000000 ,1161649.19000000, 1175576.25000000 ,1126753.31000000 ,1204843.11000000 ,1183946.03000000, 1153080.36000000, 1120182.07000000, 1104726.03000000 ,1108110.02000000 ,1137729.28000000 ,1189699.45000000, 1252975.55000000, 1218118.20000000 ,1259580 ,1208193 ,1194430, 1244458, 1218867, 1205705 ,1177362, 1185584, 1164758, 1226991 ,1286044 ,1305312, 1360681.70000000 ,1332020 ,1306497.90000000 ,1299819.10000000 ,1316167.70000000 ,1246959.40000000 ,1256700.20000000 ,1266490.60000000, 1275642.90000000, 1358839.80000000, 1361440.10000000, 1398059.40000000];
data = iddata(rawdat',[]);
sys = ar(data,4);
K = 49;
p = forecast(sys,data,K);
plot(data,'b',p,'r'), legend('measured','forecasted')
```

Notice that I also changed the initial data's variable name and type.

The above code leads to the following figure.
[image: forecast figure]

Please update us. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still working on it, but you really helped me.

Comment: Do you know how I use an array of variables instead of typing the data manually? Because I tried it a few times and it always showed an error message.

Comment: @SrnLord could you provide an example of what you mean by an array of variables?